# How to get host under a host group, By Ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zabbix

I am able to get the host group id by

```
puts zbx.hostgroups.get(:name => "Dev" )
```

give this o/p

```
{"groupid"=>"13", "name"=>"Dev", "internal"=>"0", "flags"=>"0"}
```

But I want to get all the nodes under this host group. Although I tried in other way like
get all host under this host group but I didnt find groupid attribute in host please refer below o/p

```
puts zbx.hosts.get(:host => "ip-10-10-111-11.ec2.internal")
```

> {"maintenances"=>[], "hostid"=>"10251", "proxy_hostid"=>"10109",
>   "host"=>"ip-10-10-111-11.ec2.internal", "status"=>"0",
>   "disable_until"=>"0", "error"=>"", "available"=>"1",
>   "errors_from"=>"0", "lastaccess"=>"0", "ipmi_authtype"=>"0",
>   "ipmi_privilege"=>"2", "ipmi_username"=>"", "ipmi_password"=>"",
>   "ipmi_disable_until"=>"0", "ipmi_available"=>"0",
>   "snmp_disable_until"=>"0", "snmp_available"=>"0",
>   "maintenanceid"=>"0", "maintenance_status"=>"0",
>   "maintenance_type"=>"0", "maintenance_from"=>"0",
>   "ipmi_errors_from"=>"0", "snmp_errors_from"=>"0", "ipmi_error"=>"",
>   "snmp_error"=>"", "jmx_disable_until"=>"0", "jmx_available"=>"0",
>   "jmx_errors_from"=>"0", "jmx_error"=>"",
>   "name"=>"ip-10-10-111-11.ec2.internal", "flags"=>"0", "templateid"=>"0"}

I didnot find any relation between hosts & hostgroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working in the below manner

```
host_grps =  zbx.query(
    :method => "host.get",
    :params => {
        "output" => "extend",
        "groupids" => [14]
    }
)
puts host_grps
```

Its gives host groups in list of hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

A simple JSON request for method `host.get` with the following parameters gives me information for all hosts that belong to the specified groups:

```
{ "output" : "extend", "groupids": [ "4", "12" ] }
```

Please consult [host.get API documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/api/reference/host/get) for more information.

Comment: I am Sorry @asaveljevs. I tried to run this 

`puts zbx.hosts.get( { :output => "extend", :groupids => [ "1" ] })`
but it is giving list of all hosts irrespective of specific groupid=1 and if you see above o/p of host.get you can see that there is no groupids attribute by which we can relate both of them.

Comment: Which Zabbix version are you using?

Comment: Thanks  @asaveljevs. I got it working. By the way I was using >zabbixapi-2.2.1.gem 
>zabbix server version Zabbix 2.2.5